# How do I check to see if a JMS listener is active?

Tags: jms, listener, spring-jms

I built a JMS listener to point at an SQS queue, and I've sent messages to the queue, but unfortunately they're not getting picked up off of it. How do I check to make sure the listener is active and ready to accept new messages. For clarity, here's the code with unnecessary pieces stripped out:

```
@Component
@Conditional(SqsListeningEnabledCondition.class)
public class SqsJobListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SqsJobListener.class);
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final JobFactoryMap jobFactoryMap;
    private final CacheManager cacheManager;

    @Autowired
    public SqsJobListener() {
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "${aws.job.queue}", containerFactory = "customListenerContainerFactory", concurrency = "1")
    public void receiveIngestionMessage(String message) {

       //deserializing bits here
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "see"? Do you mean something programmatic you can use from the client-side? Do you mean something administrative you can use from the server-side? Your question is too vague.

Comment: I mean something as a dev, from either client or server side. A quick wellness check to see if it's accepting messages

Comment: Does SQS not have a management console, that lets you check whether consumers are properly registered? Most messaging products have something like this.